# Create one Makefile rule for several files

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I would like to create just one Makefile rule instead of creating the same rule for different files of the same type.

Consider this small example where a `files` declare two Python-Notebooks and each of these Notebooks should be converted into a Python-Script (`.py`). This can be done with the command `jupyter nbconvert --to script FILE`. The Makefile I tried to create looks like this but is **not** working:

```
files = A.ipynb B.ipynb

all: convert

convert: $(files)   
     jupyter nbconvert --to script $<      # How to define $< as the changed file?
```

Now, whenever `A.ipynb` is changed, I would like the command

```
jupyter nbconvert --to script A.ipynb
```

to be executed. Can this be done within one simple rule as 'suggested' above? I can write a Makefile accomplishing the task but its longer and scales with the size of `files`:

```
all: A.py B.py

A.py: A.ipynb
    jupyter nbconvert --to script $<

B.py: B.ipynb
    jupyter nbconvert --to script $<
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what [pattern rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Rules.html) are for:

```
all: A.py B.py

%.py: %.ipynb
        jupyter nbconvert --to script $<
```

You can also use [static pattern rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-Pattern.html) which some prefer.

Comment: Thank you! Was reading about static patterns but couldnt make the transfer. So this
````$(files): %.py: %.ipynb
     jupyter nbconvert --to script $<```` would be a static pattern?

Comment: Yes, assuming that `files := A.py B.py`